# Unite types under one protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

What is the best way to unite to unrelated types under one protocol, e.g. to use that new type as an element type for an array?

*e.g.*: 
Third-party-provided class `Foo` and class `Bar` are unrelated, however, I would like to create an array which contains elements of types  `Foo` *and* `Bar`. Note that I can't change the implementation of `Foo` and `Bar` directly.

One approach might be:

```
protocol FooBar {}
extension Foo: FooBar {}
extension Bar: FooBar {}
```

However, this strikes me as odd and rather unappealing, since there are no implementations – are there other ways?

I will enumerate through that array and process the Elements knowing that it can be either `Foo` or `Bar` inside.

Comment: Have `Foo` and `Bar` inherit from the same base class?

Comment: @JAL No, otherwise the solution would be clear.

Comment: _"I would like to create an Array which contains Element types of Foo and Bar"_ How do you plan to use this array?

Comment: @AntonBronnikov I will enumerate through that array and process the Elements knowing that it can be either Foo or Bar inside.

Comment: @ff10 that sounds... suspicious.

Comment: @sunilsharma Please stop adding the [tag:ios] tag to every Swift question you see. There is *nothing* iOS-specific about this question. "Getting more attention" isn't the point - we could also add [tag:javascript] and [tag:php] while we're at it, and get even more attention; but they -- like [tag:ios] -- would be irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I should use a generic type here...

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer directly to your question, but given that you only want to iterate through the array that contains `Foo`s and `Bar`s you could use `enum` like:

```
enum FooBar {
    case WrappedFoo(Foo)
    case WrappedBar(Bar)
}
```

This will at least save you from having to do `as?` with every element in order to get the exact type you are dealing with.

Example:

```
// Some setup
var arr: [FooBar] = []

let foo = Foo()
let bar = Bar()

arr.append(.WrappedFoo(foo))
arr.append(.WrappedFoo(foo))
arr.append(.WrappedBar(bar))
arr.append(.WrappedFoo(foo))
arr.append(.WrappedBar(bar))
arr.append(.WrappedBar(bar))

// Enumeration
arr.forEach {
    switch $0 {
    case .WrappedFoo(let foo):
        // do something with `foo`
    case .WrappedBar(let bar):
        // do something with `bar`
    }
}
```